# TFS Build fail path too long

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I've this error: 
[image]

I follow this article http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/build-fails-path-limit-exceeded , but I have always the same error. I'd like this error happens suddently, I launched my Build Definitions a lot of time, and programmed a lot.

Do you have an idea to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have shorten the build agent's Working Directory and the Workspace Mappings that mentioned in the link your posted above. That is the solution for this error.

And I also researched some other solution that you could try:

[TFS Build error - "The specified path, file name, or both are too long..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226058/tfs-build-error-the-specified-path-file-name-or-both-are-too-long)

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/47491/build-fails-with-the-specified-path-file-name-or-both-are-too-long-in-obj-folder

Comment: I used the tool longpathtool to find which file does not fit. Thank you!